# jQuery UI autocomplete returns "Request-URI Too Large"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm trying to use [jQuery.autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data) without using callback. My JSON data source is stored in a JS varaible. The point of this is to avoid make a serve call.

But when I try using autocomplete, I keep getting the error message

> Request-URI Too Large

This is my code:

```
// This list is much longer
country_data_source =   [{"id":"AF","name":"Afghanistan"},{"id":"AL","name":"Albania"},{"id":"DZ","name":"Algeria"},{"id":"AS","name":"American Samoa"},{"id":"AD","name":"Andorra"},{"id":"AO","name":"Angola"}]

jQuery( "#country" ).autocomplete({
  minLength: 0,
  source: country_data_source
 });
```

Is jQuery still using POST/GET thus giving me this error due to browser restriction?

**Note: ** If I just use the short list above, autocomplete is not responding at all.
Even tried `$.getJSON(country_data_source)`

Comment: What is the actual request that is being sent to the server?

Comment: It would appear that the array is being treated as a string, and `autocomplete` is using it as a URL (for which it may be too long).

Comment: Have you tried to remove the 'datatype' key? In the linked example, they don't seem to use it, maybe this will trigger a request?

Comment: `dataType` is not a valid argument for the autocomplete widget. It's having no effect.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker thanks for clearing that up, was just thinking out loud. The dataType key looked suspicious. To OP; is an actual request *made*? I.e., can you see a request being sent in firebug?

Comment: No request is sent to server. That's what I'm trying to avoid. I'm using a lot of autocomplete, but it's the first time I try without server request.

Comment: Working for me, can you modify this fiddle to reproduce your problem : http://jsfiddle.net/UQTY2/41/

Comment: Yes, just replace "value" with "name". That's why it's failing. See @lib3d's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Autocomplete may not understand your array as a local source because its not made of objects each being made of a "label" and a "value" attribute. In your case you provided an id and a name that are not what it expects. 
You will have to transform this array'objects, or you may only provide an array of strings that will be used as labels. 
Because jQuery UI Autocomplete does not find what it is searching for in your array, it switches to the next interpretation: a url.